# Facebook online indicator does not appear for certain profile

Tags: facebook

Why can't I see the last login time timestamp or online green circle or cell phone icon only for one certain profile?

I can open this user profile without problems.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: @keral the OP is actually asking about the Facebook site, though the question would apply to the app as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks to be about a mobile app instead of a web app.

Answer (score 2):

- Friends with a green dot next to their name are on chat or Messenger.
- Friends with a phone icon next to their name have downloaded one of the Facebook apps (e.g., Facebook for iPhone and Android). These friends can see your chat messages on their phones.
- Friends with no icon next to their names are off chat. Chats you send them will go directly to their messages inbox.

So here in your screenshot that person is offline and does not use Facebook apps.